# Calculate the arithmetic mean of a random variable

Tags: statistics, means

Suppose that the results of a measurement (of let's say the number of citizens of a town, which is modeled by the random variable $X$) are given as follows:

> Out of 4000 towns:
>
> a) 500 have less than 10000 citizens;
>
> b) 1500 have between 10000 and 100000 citizens;
>
> c) 1500 have between 100000 and 1000000 citizens;
>
> d) 500 have more than 1000000 citizens

My question is: how would I be able to calculate the average number of citizens per town (i.e. $\bar X$)?

Comment: You can only estimate it. Consider category d, and the possibility you have a town with one trillion citizens.  There is not sufficient information to compute a mean here.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to estimate the mean is to take the midpoint of each class as the representative value for each class (however inaccurate the estimate is then likely to be) simply because you have no more accurate information.

So we would take $5000$ as the value for the first class, $55000$ for the second class, and so on, and work out an estimate from there, i.e.  $$\bar{X}\simeq\frac{500\times5000+1500\times55000+...}{4000}$$